# How to read and save notification limit to database for each element of a Java RDD

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to Apache Spark. I am writing a program in which I create a JavaRDD by fetching data from Apache Cassandra database. Then I process each element in RDD by invoking some helper methods which are not part of my driver program.

In the helper method based on certain conditions I want to send email notification. But before that I want to get the number of notifications already sent to that user. If it does not exceed the limit then I want to send the notification and increase the notification number in database for that user.

So how can I get this data and also update this in database when I am not in driver program and I do not have sparkContext in my helper method?

Please suggest. I am using Apache Spark 2.0.0 and Spark Cassandra Java connector

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on executors only, because they don't synchroniza state with each other. But you can try this solution:

1. Rewrite your helper method to return a dataframe with schema `(user, notification)` for every notification of every user you want to send
2. Perform `collect_list` aggregation on this dataframe (the schema will change to `(user, [notif1, notif2, ...])`
3. Load data of already sent notifications to new dataframe, for example `(user, remaining_notifications_number)`
4. Join datasets from (2) and (3) and for each result sent number of notifications that is not exceeding limit.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you @Mariusz. I will try this way.